# Missing ".TH" section when converting .rst file to groff format in pandoc (reStructuredText, manpage)

Tags: documentation, pandoc, restructuredtext, manpage, groff

What should I put in a source reStructuredText file to populate the "Title Heading" (`.TH`) line in the destination file when using `pandoc` to convert it to groff-format?

I have a python project whose documentation is built with sphinx. As such, most of the project's documentation is already written in reStructured Text (`.rst` files). I need to write a manpage, so I'd like to write it in reST format.

Unfortunately, when I use `pandoc` to convert the source `.rst` file to `man` (groff-format), the file doesn't render properly with `man` since it's missing the Title Heading.

For example, consider the following source file `source.rst`

```
==========
my-program
==========

----------------------
my-program description
----------------------

:manual section: 1
:manual group: John Doe

Synopsis
========

**my-program**

Description
===========

**my-program** is magical. It does what you need!
```

I use `pandoc` to convert it to groff format as follows:

```
user@disp117:~$ pandoc source.rst -t man > my-program.1
user@disp117:~$ 

user@disp117:~$ cat my-program.1 
.SH my-program
.SS my-program description
.TP
manual section
1
.TP
manual group
John Doe
.SS Synopsis
.PP
\f[B]my-program\f[R]
.SS Description
.PP
\f[B]my-program\f[R] is magical.
It does what you need!
user@disp117:~$
```

Now, if I try to render that groff file, then it doesn't format properly.

```
user@disp117:~$ groffer --text my-program.1 
manual  section  1 manual group John Doe my‐program my‐program is
magical.  It does what you need!
...
```

However, if I manually add the a `.TH` line to the file, then it works as expected.

```
user@disp117:~$ echo -e ".TH my_program(1)\n$(cat my-program.1)" > my-program.1
user@disp117:~$ 

user@disp117:~$ groffer --text my-program.1 
my_program(1)()                                                my_program(1)()



my-program
   my-program description
       manual section
              1

       manual group
              John Doe

   Synopsis
       
       [B]my-program
                    [R]

   Description
       
       [B]my-program
                    [R] is magical.  It does what you need!



                                                               my_program(1)()
user@disp117:~$
```

What do I need to add to `source.rst` such that `pandoc` will produce a file in groff-format that includes the `.TH` line?

Comment: This question seems more about using tools than about programming, so Super User might be a more appropriate Stack Exchange site for this question. That said, in general this is still a good question :)

Comment: @ShaneBishop you're right, but the StackExchange community [decided](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295180/where-to-ask-pandoc-questions) that pandoc questions are well accepted on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc generates "snippets" by default; those snippets are intended to be integrated into a complete document. Make pandoc generate a complete document with

```bash
   pandoc --standalone ...
```

or

```bash
   pandoc -s ...
```